# Drupal 7 Webform fills hidden field with current node title

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm using a webform as a block on all the pages from a specific content type. The form is the same in all, but on the list of submissions I want to know which page the user was seeing. I thought a hidden field, and a default value of `%title` would do it, but it's not the case. I tried a bunch of other token values, and a lot of them do work, but none of them gives me an identifier of the current node.

Comment: 7, it's in the question title :)

Comment: My bad it's very late! Just off to have a quick look will report back soon :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason it's not working is because the `node` element of the webform tokens refers to the node of the webform itself, not the current node page. Why webform doesn't use the in-built token system I have no idea, seems like a missed opportunity.

Looking at the webform module I think the easiest way to get this done is to write a quick custom module defining a single table (two columns, `nid` and `url`) and then implement `hook_webform_submission_insert()` to save the current `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for all webforms. You can then use `hook_webform_submission_load()` and `hook_webform_submission_render_alter()` respectively to re-attach the URL data to the submission and display it to the page.

You can find all of those hooks in the `webform_hooks.php` file included in the module, they're pretty well documented.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't actually made any custom modules, but I think I'll definitely look into this. Do you know if there's a way to get the "current node" from the page you're seeing? (so instead of getting `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` I actually get the node's title or whatever)

Comment: another idea I had is to just use some quick and dirty jQuery and load `$('h1').text()` into the damn hidden field... but it seems dirty and won't work if JS is disabled

Comment: Yeah that's not ideal, another idea might be to use a [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to populate the hidden field, that way it'll work for non-JS users. You can use [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) if you're on a node page to get the node object

Comment: Just for reference, this is what I ended up doing (thanks a lot!), in a custom module:

    `function funnygarbage_form_webform_client_form_22_alter(&$form, &$form_state)
    {
     $current_object = menu_get_object();
     if ($current_object->type != 'job')
      return;
     $job_title = $current_object->title;
     
     $form['submitted']['job_position']['#default_value'] = $job_title;
    }`

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on this solution? In particular, is the naming of this function important?